# New Button of Document Set - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, content-type, document-set, new-document

I created a Document Set with a Document Set Content Type Project. 
However, the Library does not display a "New" button where I can select "New Project" but only a "new document" button where I can upload a new document.

I have no idea why it doesn't work and searched all over the internet. 
When I click on "Change New Button Order", the Project Content Type is marked Visible and on Position one.

But where is the new button in my Library?

Thank you for any help with this!

Comment: Okay, I think I found the answer here: [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85056/how-to-disable-the-new-document-option-in-a-library-which-is-supposed-to-be-for?rq=1][1]

Answer (score 0):

To use any content type other than the default one you have to use the ribbon. In the ribbon use the caret under NEW DOCUMENT and you should see the Project content type.